# App crashed when the return button is clicked

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent, onactivityresult

I'm trying to pass value k from Activity A to B. When the save `button` in the activity B is clicked, it will pass the value k to Activity A again. But the app crashed if I want to return back to A.

Some code snippet in Activity A

```
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (item == 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Project1.class);
                       intent.putExtra("k",k);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                    } else if (item == 1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Petrol.class);
                       intent.putExtra("k", k);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    }

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        int button = data.getIntExtra("k1", 0);
        if (button == 1) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 0:
                    String result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    String b = data.getStringExtra("a");
                     as=Long.parseLong(result);
                    c.setText("            " + b + "------" + "RM " + result);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    String result1 = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    String b1 = data.getStringExtra("a");
                     as1=Long.parseLong(result1);
                    c.setText("            " + b1 + "------" + "RM " + result1);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if(button==2)
        {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 0:
                    String result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    String b = data.getStringExtra("a");
                     bs=Long.parseLong(result);
                    d.setText("            " + b + "------" + "RM " + result);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    String result1 = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    String b1 = data.getStringExtra("a");
                     bs1=Long.parseLong(result1);
                    d.setText("            " + b1 + "------" + "RM " + result1);
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Activity B

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.project);
   txt= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText36);
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button17);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            a="Project";
            text = txt.getText().toString();
            returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
            returnIntent.putExtra("a", a);
            final int k1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("k");
            returnIntent.putExtra("k1", k1);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Project1.this, Claims.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

LogCat Error

```
10-28 15:55:26.612    3641-3641/com.example.project.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 3641
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=2, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example.project.project/com.example.project.project.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

**Latest error**

```
 10-28 16:54:56.150    6381-6381/com.example.project.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 6381
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.project.project/com.example.project.project.Claims}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.project.project.Claims cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
```

I did like what @we are borg suggested and declare the activity A (claims.java) in mainfest.xml, but get the error as above

Thanks everyone...I did like this and it solved :)

**Activity A**
declare   `public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 6;`
  add `else if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {}after else if(button==5){}`

**Activity B**

Use

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

instead of  @Override

```
 public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Project1.this, Claims.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Where is your onBackPressed() function?

Comment: I'm using the back button that emulator provided, not the button I created

Comment: show your onActivityResult() code

Comment: Would you please provide a little more consistent ("Activity B"? Petrol or Project1?) context, and let us know which line is actually causing the exception?

Comment: @HannoBinder Petrol and Project1 has the same code

Comment: You do check the [`resultCode`](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html#ReceiveResult) for `RESULT_OK`/`RESULT_CANCELED`, don't you?

Comment: Can you add the activity result code? and yes give a full error log.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your prompt reply..I just edited my post..

Comment: @HannoBinder Can you explain it more?

Comment: @HardikChauhan done....

Comment: See the link in my comment and the answer @m0rphine gave.

Comment: Your code is missing the check on the `resultCode` in `onActivityResult`. Add that and you should be good.

Comment: "Hidden" under the word `resultCode` - just click it :)

Comment: @HannoBinder why  overide method onBackPressed in activity B does not work ? Or I need to use both?

Comment: I guess either one will work. No need to use both together. It depends on what you want to do: If you don't want a normal cancelling action to happen for the "back" button, i.e. cancelling the current activity and returning to the previous, then override `onBackPressed` and implement whatever you need. Else just check the resultCode after return.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93747/discussion-between-hoo-and-hanno-binder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, shamelessly copy-pasting from the official docs at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

            // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you have the `if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)` line in your code. If `(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)`, then no result will be available and the `Intent` is `null`.

When you press the "back" button on your device the normal result is the cancellation of the current activity, hence the calling activity gets the `resultCode` of `RESULT_CANCELED` in that case and not the one you set when explicitly returning via `finish()`.

Comment: But it doesn't work if I use the overrideBackPressed only...see the latest logcat

Answer (score 5):

When you press back button, as default result code will be  RESULT_CANCEL and returning intent will be null.

You need to check it in *onActivityResult* or override method *onBackPressed* in activity B and set necessary result values.

Edited:

Override *onBackPressed* in following way (activity B)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    a="Project";
    text = txt.getText().toString();
    returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
    returnIntent.putExtra("a", a);
    final int k1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("k");
    returnIntent.putExtra("k1", k1);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

In that case you'll send back necessary result values.

If you don't want to send any value on back button pressed, you can check result code in *onActivityResult*

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // int button = data.getIntExtra("k1", 0); // data could be null. and here you are getting NullPointerException
    // if (button == 1) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 String result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                String b = data.getStringExtra("a");
                as=Long.parseLong(result);
                c.setText("            " + b + "------" + "RM " + result);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCEL) {
                // TODO other functionality - when you do not override onBackPressed in activity B
            }
            break;
            ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this function in your class :

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, DestinationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

I hope this is what you are looking for, if not, I will remove the answer, just leave a comment.

Comment: If you want to go from activity B to activity A, then this method you should write in Acitivity B. And the first parameter for new Intent is (ActivityB.class, ActivityA.class);

Comment: Ok, activity A extend to fragment and B extend to activity...now the compiler ask me declare A in mainfest.xml

Comment: That's correct, declare it then. This question is solved, that's another problem. Accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: This is a different question and like I said, declare it in manifest. Over and out.

Comment: Sorry bro, I just edited my logcat...please have a look

Answer (score -1):

I think 'null object reference' is coming because of the `getActivity()`.
Check if the `getActivity()` is not returning null if it is than use context.
Or create a singleton object.

Comment: Actually it looks like the Intent is null in onActivityResult due to him clicking back instead of the button.

Comment: Hmmm can be ok lets see if he can provide more code.